# Check each value in a dataframe and if that is less means then change the value which is given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
cateory Percentage
    AB      99
    CD      65
    EF      12
    GH      25
    IJ      90
    KL      100
```

If CD's percentage is less than 70 then change that as 71 else existing value is fine
If EF's percentage is less than 20 then change that as 21 else existing value is fine
If GH's percentage is less than 30 then change that as 45 else existing value is fine
For AB existing value is fine

Output

```
cateory Percentage
    AB      99
    CD      65
    EF      21
    GH      45
    IJ      90
    KL      100
```

Comment: @jezrael pls see this

Comment: I think `CD` should be `71`, because `65` is less like `70`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create list of tuples for replacement by compare both columns and if match replace by `new` value - last value of tuple:

```
L = [('CD', 70, 71), ('EF', 20, 21), ('GH', 30, 45)]

for cat, less, new in L:
    m = df['cateory'].eq(cat) & df['Percentage'].lt(less)
    df.loc[m, 'Percentage'] = new
print (df)
  cateory  Percentage
0      AB          99
1      CD          71
2      EF          21
3      GH          45
4      IJ          90
5      KL         100
```